# Could not load type 'type_name' from assembly 'assembly_name'

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have been struggling with this for more than 3 hours.
I have a project 'project1' that contains an interface : 'interface1'

but when I deploy the project on IIS (it's wcf app), I get this exception :

Could not load type 'interface1' from assembly 'project1'.

Answer (score 4):

Check if you have older version of the assembly in the GAC. Also attach debugger and check Debug->Modules view to see where you assembly is loaded from.

In general for cases of strange assembly loading problems (like this one - can't find particular type in some assembly) configure and use fuslogvw to see what asseblies are actually loaded.

Comment: I've checked the GAC and the assembly doesn't exist there.

Comment: I just started fuslogvw and every entry related to the assembly in question shows a success. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: FusLogVW should show exatc location where assembly was loaded from. Make sure that the location contains latest version of the code.

Comment: I got the same error with WCF.  I just had to update the assembly in the service directory.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem by erasing and starting over with the configuration file.